# Invalid type for argument in function call for array

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am currently a beginner to solidity programming. However, I am getting an error when I try to send an array for an argument for a function.

```
constructor() {
    addQuestion('Is this a question?', ['Yes', 'No']);
}

function addQuestion(string memory _title, string[] memory _answers) private {
    ...
}
```

I am getting an error that implicit conversion from 'string memory[2] memory' to 'string memory[] memory' requested